# Converting cer (with csr and key) to pfx

Tags: openssl, certificate, converters

¿I can make a  `PFX` certificate from `cer`, `csr` and `key` files?

Actually I have this files

- ceti.cer
- ceti.csr
- ceti.key

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Command has been fixed. Be sure your ceti.cer is PEM encoded

You could use the command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ceti.pfx -inkey ceti.key -in ceti.cer
```

Comment: I tried and get this message `Loading 'screen' into random state - done
No certificate matches private key` and create a empty ceti.pfx file

Comment: The OpenSSL pkcs12 command says : "The filename to read certificates and private keys from, standard input by default. They must all be in PEM format" (http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkcs12.html). You can convert them from DER encoded to PEM encoded if this is not the case.

Comment: Command does not work with Ubuntu 17.10. The error message "Unable to load certificates" appears, but the files given with -inkey, -in and -certfile exists. Don't know what to do now.

Comment: @Freude take a look at this other question/answer : https://serverfault.com/questions/473155/unable-to-load-certificate-in-openssl

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong; the `-in` file should be the certificate, not the signing request

Answer (score 2):

This command helped me:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.pfx -inkey user.key -in user.cer -certfile rootca.crt
```

the responses above returned an error "Unable to load certificates".

Answer (score 1):

The -in should be .cer file and the -certfile should be .cabundle.pem, you don't need the csr request once it have been signed by root/intermediate CA. So the correct syntax is:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -out ceti.pfx -inkey private.key -in signed.cer
>   -certfile cabundle.pem

to bundle the root/intermediate pem files run something like:

> cat root.crt intermediateca.crt subordinateca.crt > cabundle.pem

Answer (score 1):

You should convert .csr, .key to crt firstly. Please refer my step:

1. openssl x509 -req -in myDomainName.csr -signkey myDomainName.key -out myDomainName.crt
2. openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey myDomainName.key -in myDomainName.crt